# Extract Audio from Jar file

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, decompiling

So, I'm trying to extract the music from a Java Mobile game.
It's Block Breaker Deluxe 2.
Unfortunately there is nothing on the Internet about it, pretty much. At least about the music.
I used to play this game a lot years and years ago.
I want to extract the music for personal use. Just to listen.
When I open the file with the Java Decompiler, I only get the class files and so. Plus some other files which appear to be data.
This is where I got the file from: [download link](http://www.4shared.com/postDownload/kAF0x4Ef/Block_Breaker_Deluxe_2_240x320.html)

I know that many of the files are either PNGs or classes. What about the music?

Comment: Why not just to un-zip it. Rename your .jar file to .zip, extract it to folder and find your music file.

Comment: @Maksim That what I did in first place. But I didn't find any audio files there.

Comment: they could be named anything, and may not actually have an extension.

Comment: If you can't find the music assets, you may need to inspect the decompiled source to see how they are loaded.

Comment: @MikeStrobel It seems to call java functions to play it. getResourceAsStream and so. I am not a Java developer, so I'm not used to Java. I know some files that seem to be called by the game. It's visibl when using an emulator showing the log. I inspected those files and they seem to have no header. Then I found on the Internet that .au files are commonly used on jar files, plus, they have no header, just the raw data. So I changed the extension to .au and non of my players could play that.